# URL Rewrite wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite my posts url in wordpress using add_rewrite_rule. Only if query_var action is set.
Example: `example.com/my-post-name-slug/?action=query_action`
To: `example.com/my-post-name-slug/query_action`

Is it possible?

htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /hot/
RewriteRule ^ajax/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ /hot/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=$1&movie_id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^\?action\=$ 
RewriteCond ^\?action\= ^/?$

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /hot/index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

UPDATE: Solve

```
add_rewrite_rule('^slug/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=tpp&name=$matches[1]&action-query=$matches[2]','top');
```